# exception handling in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, exception

I am a newbie to ruby on rails and developing some email apps, which uses AWS SES to send emails. I am uploading a csv file which contains only email address and an email will be sent to those email address.

Its a very basic app, which my app fails to send an email due to some reasons the app automatically stops sending emails. But I has to keep sending emails to the remaining email address.

How do I handle the exception. I have used ActionMailer.

Kindly Help me

Comment: Kindly post some relevant code.  We can't read minds.

Comment: I just parse the CSV file and call the ActionMailer in my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def send_all_emails
  @emails.each do |email|
    send_one_mail email
  end
end

def send_one_mail email
  # your actual email sending code here
rescue
  # this will log error to Rails log, but will not halt the whole app
  Rails.logger.error $!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know about the exception,use

```
begin
 #some code here
rescue =>ex
 Rails.logger.error "#{ex.class.name} :  #{ex.message}"
end
```

ps: You can also use **rescue Exception =>ex** .But don't use it until needed.Since it will catch all minor exceptions like 'NoMemoryError' which we don't want.Use the first one,it will catch only the Standard errors.